# WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

Estoy tratando de usar Selenium en Python 2.7 y me tira el siguiente mensaje de error.

> WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but
>   unable to find binary in default location, no
>   'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag
>   set on the command line

Que puede ser?

Comment: Parece que no le has indicado la ruta donde esta el ejecutable del webdriver para levantar firefox.

Comment: Pablo tienes [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) instalado en ese sistema?

Comment: @FJSevilla , sisi, antes no estaba en path pero ahora lo encuentra y me abre una ventana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo así te falta:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('F:\FirefoxPortable\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```